# How can I make use of the focus point in android's ScaleGestureDetector to zoom just like android browser?

Tags: android, canvas, scale, viewport, pinchzoom

I have a canvas that I am using a ScaleGestureDetector to zoom in my android app.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
        //SCALING --------------------------------------------------
        //get center of the viewport
        int centerX = xLoc+((int)(screenWidth/2*scaleFactor));
        int centerY = yLoc+((int)(screenHeight/2*scaleFactor));
        scaleFactor /= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        scaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(scaleFactor, maxScaleFactor));                
        //Make sure the viewport is repositioned
        xLoc = centerX-((int)(screenWidth/2*scaleFactor));
        yLoc = centerY-((int)(screenHeight/2*scaleFactor));
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
```

This works great to zoom in and out of my canvas.  The xLoc and yLoc represent the top left corner of my viewport in relation to the entire image I am drawing a portion of.        The problem I have with this code though, is that It zooms in to the center of the viewport.  I would like to be able to use detector.getFocuxX() and detector.getFocusY() to zoom into the 
focus point, just like the pinch to zoom works in the android browser.

Basically I need to adjust the position of the viewport (xLoc and yLoc) so that it gives the appearance of zooming into the focus point of the scale gesture.

I cannot figure this part out. If anyone has an idea of how I can do this without using the canvas matrix transformations (which I have seen used in many of the topics I found before posting this) I would really appreciate it!  Even if you could point me to someone else who has done something similar.

Answer (score 0):

A single `onScale` function call does not provide enough information to implement scaling around apparent focus point. You will need to preserve values of `getFocusX()` and `getFocusY()` from a previous `onScale` call and use them to influence your scaling in the next call.

Comment: @AnjaniMittal Sadly, I no longer on the project that had implemented this and don't have access to source code.

Comment: do u remember how it was managed if the user zoomed out and the view went out of screen boundaries??

Comment: We had zoom limits

Comment: if a user zooms and then moves to the corner of the view and then zooms out , in that case the view is getting partially out of screen